# How do I get Python and Python in Visual Studio code to output the sem when using os.getcwd()?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I wanted to make it easier to edit my code on different devices with different usernames, so I decided to change how my code knows where my files are. Instead of using the entire file path, I decided to use `os.getcwd` but when I run it in Visual Studio Code I only get `C:\Users\Name` while when I run it with just python I get `C:\Users\Name\Yuna-Discord-Bot`. And for both I am using the same code:

```
import os

test=(os.getcwd())
print(test)
input("Enter to close")
```

Is there any way to get them to get Visual Studio Code to the same as just python, or vice versa?

Comment: I think you have some fundamental misunderstanding. I'm not sure what you mean by " Instead of using the entire file path, I decided to use os.getcwd" but in any case, `os.getcwd` returns... the current working directory. If you are runnig the code in different working directories, it will show you those different directories. Can you explain exactly what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: So, the answer to your question is simply "run them from the same working directory".

Comment: I'm trying to open a config file `yaml = YAML()
with open(rf"{filePath}\Yuna-Discord-Bot\config.yml", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
  config = yaml.load(file)` like this it works fine in Visual Studio Code, but if I just double click the file to run it (so no vscode) it makes `C:\\Users\\Name\\Yuna-Discord-Bot\\Yuna-Discord-Bot\\config.yml` Wich doesn't exist. I'm sorry if this is something really simple to understand. maybe I'm just not seeing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.getcwd()` returns **the directory where the running file is located** if you run the file directly **in the terminal or double-click**.

However if you run the file **in vscode** it should be noted that no matter where the file you are running, the cwd you get will still be **the workspace** instead of the folder where the file is located (even the file is in the deep directory).

It is determined by the way vscode retrieves files.

This is also the reason for the running error in your comments, because your `{filePath}` is different for the different running way.

You can try interactive Window which is more suitable for your needs.

[image]

or you can use debug mode, and add the following line to your launch.json:

```
"cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```